# OpenLayers 6: Example Box Selection Error

Tags: openlayers, geojson, openlayers-6

Following exactly the example of the openlayers site in:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/box-selection.html?q=feature

Locally I have the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at getObject (JSONFeature.js: 197)
    at GeoJSON.JSONFeature.readFeatures (JSONFeature.js: 53)
    at VectorSource. <anonymous> (featureloader.js: 94)
```

I believe the error comes from trying to load a geojson file locally.

```
var vectorSource = new VectorSource ({
  url: 'data/geojson/countries.geojson',
  format: new GeoJSON ()
});
```

**countries.geojson:**
https://r68tk.csb.app/data/geojson/countries.geojson

[image]

How to solve?

Comment: https://r68tk.csb.app/box-selection.html is working correctly for me.,  However https://r68tk.csb.app/data/box-selection.html  also runs the application but doesn't work correctly as it tries to load https://r68tk.csb.app/data/data/geojson/countries.geojson

Comment: curious to be working for you if you are with this version 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

In the process of developing an application in OpenLayers, unfortunately there are problems loading files locally (geojson, png etc.) due to **CORS**.

**The problem:**
[image]

An excellent text on the subject [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server).

To solve the problem, I used the Chrome extension called "[moesif CORS extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-orign-cors-changer/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=en-US)".

With it enabled, I could easily load the .geojson file.

**It was a success!**
[image]

There are even more ways to stop CORS for your development environment at this address: [https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow -origin-works-d97d55946d9](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow%20-origin-works-d97d55946d9)

I hope to help someone with this information!